# stop rdp to deactivation session after close

Tags: vpn, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, vnc

I try to run VNC Server on my Server2012 R2 (VM on HyperV Host). I login via RDP (mstsc.exe) to a Windows Server 2012 R2. Connect via real VNC to the Server also. After closing the Windows RDP connection, the windows session gets deactivated and my VNC screen logging out.

I need to connect via vnc because the cisco vpn tool running on Server is not allowing to be used while using a remote desktop connection. I also tried to open HyperV Command line and connect to the VM directly, but unfortunately its not asking for user credentials when i try to connect to the HyperV

How can I disable this deactivate-session behaviour or use HyperV console connection Programm?

Comment: Why are you doing both? Why not just use one or the other? Choose RDP or VNC.

Comment: RDP will be recognized by the vpn client. And VNC does not connect without an open windows session connection